# Connect to rasa shell of a already started rasa server

Tags: docker-compose, rasa-core, rasa

I have a rasa-docker compose file where my rasa image is based on **rasa:1.6.1-spacy-en**

```
version: '3.0'
services:
 rasa_movie:
   image: myrasa:v3
   ports:
     - 5005:5005
   depends_on:
     - duckling
     - action_server
   command:
     - run
     - -m
     - /app/models
     - --cors
     - "*"
     - --enable-api
     - --log-file
     - out.log
     - -p
     - '5005'
 action_server:
   image: myaction:v1
   ports:
     - "5055:5055"
   command:
     - start
     - --actions
     - actions
 duckling:
   image: rasa/duckling
   ports:
     - "8000:8000"
```

After doing a **docker-compose up -d**, I want to connect to **shell** of the already started ras server to interact with the bot.
I tried something like `docker exec rasacontainername rasa shell` but it  fails with **OSError: [Errno 98] error while attempting to bind on address ('0.0.0.0', 5005): address already in use** as expected.

Is there a way I can connect to the rasa shell without starting the rasas server again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The command line chat interface is directly wired to function starting the server in https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/blob/2.6.2/rasa/core/run.py#L131. So, in oder to be able to connect the command line chat interface you need to write a small script and put it into your e.g. `cmdline_chat.py`, container (assuming 5005 is the rasa server's port):

```py
import asyncio
import uuid

from rasa.core import constants
from rasa.core.channels import console

asyncio.run(console.record_messages(
    server_url=constants.DEFAULT_SERVER_FORMAT.format("http", 5005),
    sender_id=uuid.uuid4().hex,
))
```

Then, run the script instead of invoking rasa shell (`docker exec -it containername python cmdline_chat.py`).

Answer (score 0):

To interact with a running Docker Container you can do so by:

```
docker exec -it <container-name> <command>
```

---

In your specific case it should be something like

```
docker exec -it rasa_movie rasa shell
```

Here the [Docker exec docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)

Comment: Thank for trying. But this wont work because docker exec -it docker name rasa shell, wont work because it will again start the server at same port and port already in use error will come